# Drawable: making it fit the screen, and scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, drawable

I have a drawable which i want to display. I want it to fit the screen horizontally, and to be scrollable vertically (when its height is bigger than the screen), while keeping it scaled.

I'm putting the drawable into a `ImageView`. The drawable is changeable (pictures of different heights and widths). I could scale every drawable to fit to the width of the screen, but when I do the drawable's higher than the screen will get cut of at the top, and i get a black bar at the bottom of my `ScrollView`.

I've tried every combination of ScrollView and ImageView I could think of, but the Image is either stretched or part of it falls out. Any help is much appreciated!

My current code:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 />
```

But I am not sure this is able to make image bigger than parent height. If this don't help I try to find in my archive working solution.

Comment: may be the scale type should be centerCrop instead of centerInside .Look into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html